# regex to NOT match words (but case insentitive)

Tags: regex

Trying to NOT match a list of words but words are case insensitive

```
    Administrator --> not match
    aDmInIsTrAtOr --> not match
    Root          --> not match
    root          --> not match
```

but I want to accept anything else

```
    jsmith          --> match
    JSmith          --> match 
    Any_Text_Really --> match
    Any_meta_char_%$#!_and_12345 --> match
```

I can make the positive match for insensitive words

```
    ^(?i)administrator$|^(?i)root$
```

But fail to make it reversed ? 
Based on "(?:x)     Matches 'x' but does NOT remember the match. Also known as NON-capturing parenthesis" I tried:

```
    ^(?:(?i)administrator)$
```

But that fails too.
Any idea ?

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Sounds like you can use case-insensitivity everywhere, right? No need for an inline flag modifier (except at the beginning, if you wish)

Comment: I use a tool that is compatible with PCRE

Comment: yes, I want case insensitivity everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?i)(?!administrator|root).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Dp1alv/1/).

Comment: `^(?i)(?!administrator$|root$).+` That works (else Root1 matches). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Java, you may just do a *positive*, case insensitive, match for `administrator` and `root`, and then negate from Java:

```
String input = "administrator";
if (!input.matches("(?i)administrator|root")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Note that `String#matches` in Java by default matches the entire input, so the phrase `root administrator` would actually pass the above logic.  If you instead want to detect these words *anywhere* in the input string, then my answer would have to be adjusted.